# stty: standard input: Invalid argument error when scping files

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

When I try to scp a file to my remote server I get the following error:

```
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

This is caused by a line in my `.bashrc` file:

```
stty -ixon
```

If I remove that line, the error goes away.  however, if I remove that line, then when I ssh in, if I accidentally hit [CTRL]+S then the shell freezes and it takes me a while to figure out what happened.

Is there any way to resolve this?  to prevent that error without removing that line from `.bashrc`, or some other way to prevent [CTRL]+S from freezing the terminal?

Comment: You need to run the stty command only if it's an interactive login.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/146745/how-can-i-check-in-bash-if-a-shell-is-running-in-interactive-mode

Answer (score 1):

I assume you using xshell.
Press Ctrl+q could unlock it.
BTW, they called Ctrl+S freeze.

You could find more info xshell's keymap.